# Select single file from multiple downloaded file from an email using exchangelib

Tags: python, exchangelib

I m new to python, I m working on extracting text from .pdf and Docx after downloading files from an email using exchangelib but one email format has 2 attachments and I want to select only 2nd file.

```
for item in recent_emails:
    for attachment in item.attachments:

        if isinstance(attachment, FileAttachment):
            file_name = str(attachment.name).replace(' ', '_')
            print(file_name)
            print(file_name[1])
```

`output`

UserPic132571557.jpg

test.java@gmail.com.doc

s

e

`Want`

test.java@gmail.com.doc

How do I take the [-1] from a group of attachment results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're selecting the first element in the file name string, i.e. the second letter in the filename. You want to get the second element of `item.attachments` instead.

Assuming you want to only get the second attachment of file attachments, not any attachment, you'll need to filter the list first. something like this:

```py
file_attachments = [a for a in item.attachments if isinstance(a, FileAttachment)]
second_attachment = file_attachments[1]
# Or:
last_attachment = file_attachments[-1]
```

I'm not sure that attachments in Exchange have reliable ordering, so you may want some additional logic to ensure that you're selecting the right attachment.